# Escape user input to match page charset

Tags: javascript, character-encoding, url-encoding

Short version:

### Is there a javascript function that encodes data to match the charset of the page?

eg.

- When the charset is UTF-8, `ń`  turns into `%C5%84`
- When the charset is ISO-8859-2, `ń`  turns into `%F1`

---

Background:

I have a clientside javascript library that sends user entered data by AJAX.

It's sent as part of an ascii blob and after unblobbing (by a proxy), the data should exactly match the data that would have been sent by submitting the form normally (so that the server side logic of the site doesn't need changing)

Of course, special characters are escaped when they are sent by the browser. To match this, I have been using `encodeURIComponent()` on the data before processing it further. But now this library is being used on sites with other charsets, **for example** ISO-8859-2.

For now, I'm using this:

```
function escapeByCharset(str) {
    if (document.charset === "ISO-8859-2") {
        return escape(str);
    } else {
        return encodeURIComponent(str);
    }
}
```

But ideally, I'm looking for a general solution for all charsets.

Comment: This smells all wrong. 1) Never use `escape()`. Forget that it exists, it's broken and has been deprecated since forever. 2) What's "unblobbing"? 3) What's up with the server? It should be able to decode incoming data transparently.

Comment: On the customer's site, the browser encodes \xC584 as %F1. I want a function that will match that.

Comment: That answers none of the questions I have asked you.

Comment: 1. Not a question. 2. Turning an ascii data blob back into its constituent data. 3. I don't know, it's not my server. But it's been receiving iso-8859-2 percent encodings. They're not going to change to utf-8 for my sake.

Comment: 2) Never heard the term. I use encoding/decoding or serializing/parsing, respectively. 3) Ah, I understand, I thought it was under your control. Do you have a client-side JS library at your disposal?

Comment: Not currently using a library.

Comment: Hm, okay. Can you include your current code that sends the data? (I suppose it's an Ajax request?)

Comment: Here's a simplified version: `xhr.send("get", base64(encodeURIComponent(data)))`

Comment: What's the point of Base64-encoding the already-encoded data? For example, URL-encoded data is URL-safe, Base64-encoded data is not. I have no idea what service you are dealing with here, but this looks pretty messed-up to me. None of this should be a problem in the first place. The server is supposed to understand UTF-8, the client is supposed to send UTF-8, plain and simple. There is https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding, maybe you can use that, but be aware that converting Unicode to a legacy encoding will lead to data loss.

Comment: I feel we've lost track of the question, which is "Is there a javascript function that encodes data to match the charset of the page?
"

Comment: No, there is not. Javascript uses Unicode strings internally, they consist of characters, not bytes (!), when they are encoded for example by `encodeURIComponent()`, then UTF-8 is being used for the representation of the character in question. There is no way of getting a Javascript string into a legacy byte encoding with built-in functions, period.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function that gets the browser to encode it for you:

```
function encodeWithPageEncoding(str) {
    var pathString = "http://a.b?";
    var el = document.createElement('a');
    el.href = pathString + str;
    return el.href.slice(pathString.length +1);
}
```